# Unexpected character '#'

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, ecmascript-next

I'm using webpack to load dependencies when I run the `npm run dev` command I get this error:

> ```
> Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
> SyntaxError: D:\www\playing-with-texture-projection-in-three-js\src\lib\WebGLApp.js: Unexpected character '#' ;
>
>                        export default class WebGLApp {
>                            #updateListeners = []
>                            #tmpTarget = new THREE.Vector3()
>                            #rafID
>                            #lastTime
>
>                            constructor({
>                               background = '#000',
>                               backgroundAlpha = 1,
>                               fov = 45,
>                               near = 0.01,
>                               far = 100,
>                               ...options
>                               } = {}) {
>                               this.rend
>                            .......
>                            .......
> ```

What am I missing (I'm using plain javascript plus some libraries)?

Comment: This is a new EcmaScript language feature called private class fields. It is currently in proposal stage. You'll have to find the appropriate Babel plugin to transpile this. https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-private-class-fields/

Answer (score 1):

As @PatrickHund pointed out in the comments, it's a new feature in EcmaScript.

You have to use the `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` plugin to transform them.

Source: https://sitepoint.com/javascript-private-class-fields